# не работает CaseSensitive=true в TStringList (Lazarus, Delphi7)

Tags: сортировка, delphi-7, lazarus

Столкнулся со странным поведением TStringList (в Lazarus и Delphi7): отсутствие реакции на установку CaseSensitive:=**true**

```
    Uses SysUtils,Classes;
    Var  FList:TStringList;
    BEGIN
      if FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
      begin
         FList:= TStringList.Create;
         FList.CaseSensitive:=true;
         FList.Sorted:=true;
         FList.LoadFromFile(ParamStr(1));
         FList.SaveToFile(ParamStr(1)+'.sorted');
         FList.Free;
      end;
    END.
```

Пробовал альтернативный вариант:

```
   if FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
   begin
     FList:= TStringList.Create;
     FList.CaseSensitive:=true;
     FList.Sorted:=false;
     FList.LoadFromFile(ParamStr(1));
     FList.Sort;
     FList.SaveToFile(ParamStr(1)+'.sorted');
     FList.Free;
   end;
```

Результат то же: текст отсортирован, но без учёта регистра.

Что я делаю не так ?

Ведь не может быть, чтобы в обеих средах программирования жил один и тот же баг...

Comment: FList.CaseSensitive:=true; и FList.Sort; - после LoadFromFile

Comment: Ставил CaseSensitive:=true каждой второй строкой. Не помогло. Указывал явно `SortStyle:=sslAuto` -- тоже без толку.

Comment: Только что проверил - Всё работает
         FList:= TStringList.Create;
         FList.CaseSensitive:=true;
         FList.Add('aaa');
         FList.Add('Aaa');
         
         writeln(FList.Strings[0]);
         writeln(FList.Strings[1]);
         writeln();
         
         FList.Sort();
         
         writeln(FList.Strings[0]);
         writeln(FList.Strings[1]);

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler

Comment: У Вас кодировка в файле, который грузите в лист, какая?

Comment: Ваш код забил в Delphi 7 и Lazarus x64 v2.0.12 - всё равно не сортирует :(

Comment: Кодовая страница без разницы, т.к. в файле используются только латинские буквы + символы, а они в любой кодовой странице (DOS/cp886,cp1251,UTF8) совпадают.

Comment: Кажется, ситуация прояснилась! Проблема связана с текущей locale: https://www.delphi-club.ru/delphi/sl_sort_locale.html. В Lazarus проблема решилась установкой свойства UseLocale в False.